# Pugi XML: How to set the precision for float numbers

Tags: c++, xml, c++11, pugixml

I use pugi::XML parser and i want to set the precision for the floating point numbers. I have already used the rounding function on the float variable, but while printing with pugi::xml, it is printed with 6 decimal digits.

I use below statement to print value in C++11 :

subNode.append_child(pugi::node_pcdata).set_value(to_string(doubleVal).c_str());

Example:

```
<value>97.802000</value>
```

must be printed as

```
<value>97.802</value>
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iomanip> // setprecision
#include <sstream> // stringstream

std::string toStringPrecision(double input,int n)
{
    stringstream stream;
    stream << std::fixed << setprecision(n) << input;
    return stream.str();
}
```

Then you call it in:

```
subNode.append_child(pugi::node_pcdata).set_value(toStringPrecision(doubleVal,3).c_str());
```

Comment: Yes, this can be done. But I was looking whether it is possible to set this in XML Schema or using any other methods for set_value()

Comment: https://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#modify.nodedata they don't mention this feature